# Как открыть определенную директорию при выботе файла?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Нужно загружать файлы только из определенной директории.

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на Обзор при загрузке файла, открывалась бы только определенная директория?

Comment: если мои познания в этом не устарели, то никак. Ибо выбор файла происходит на уровне ОС. JS работает ток в браузере

Comment: Вы случайно на Apple не работаете? У них тоже часто возникают такие идеи - давайте разрешим выбирать файлы в Safari IOS только с нашего облака!